# Symmetry adapted basis from the book "Group Theoretical Methods and Their Applications"

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

This question is about group representation theory but might be a bit specific.

My question is from the following book: 
`Group Theoretical Methods and Their Applications (by E. Stiefel, A. Fässler) p.110`  (If you know group representation theory, you can directly read Ch.5)

Please see (5.29):   $$D(s)b^i_{\rho} = \sum_{\sigma=1}^{n_j} d^{(j)}_{\sigma \rho} b^i_{\sigma}$$

It looks like  $d^{(j)}_{\sigma \rho} $ is a vector and $ b^i_{\sigma}$ is also a vector, basis vectors of $V^i_j$. Then how to do this multiplication?

I am sorry I cannot provide the whole background about this question since there are too many stuffs here. So if you have read this book before, please help me.

Comment: Goggle books link: https://books.google.com/books/about/Group_Theoretical_Methods_and_Their_Appl.html?id=vdPvBwAAQBAJ